# What do to with cans that you just dented?

Tags: food-safety, canning

I just dented ten cans, moderately. Would it be safe to put them straight into the refrigerator or do I have to remove the food from the can and store it some other way?

Background:

I had around 35 cans in one of my side bags on my bicycle. However, I leaned my bicycle against the wall and it fell. The end result was dented cans. What should I do? They still seem good.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice

Comment: Before this continues: comments are for clarifications, not answers, half-answers or similar. Btw., @MathCubes welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Related, but not a dupe due to the time factor: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/92742/safety-of-tin-cans-dented-in-shipping?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you just damaged previously unharmed cans and they don’t show signs of leakage, the cans should be perfectly safe, even if you store them at room temperature.

The [US Department of Agriculture Food Safety and Inspection Service](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/shelf-stable-food-safety/ct_index/!ut/p/a1/jZFdT8IwFIZ_zS67dg7J8G5ZYmDKJiFK2Q3pWL-S0i5tdeqvt3zcYEDpuer7Pm_acw5sIIaNJh-SEy-NJmp_b8YbtEDjZFKgsp4kj2hWvS3qp6JA2fI-AOs_gCq9MX_l5Oi_fHnDA3d2Xsw5bHriBZCaGYg59YBoN1DrIGbGdMARRv0XYGTrgROU-mDsNXBwBdGdkpoHTVDFgPOkVSfvmIR46zdSd_QTrmBz_iuUhJpV6XI0LasU1aPfwIWxHYHrcwmNc2Xaw47WuW7TLHRoKaOW2vjdBll437uHCEVoGIaYG8MVjTsaoUsJYZyH-AyE_e4Vfz_nUyRfdqvM5T8VIlf1/#10) writes:

> If a can containing food has a small dent, but is otherwise in good shape, the food should be safe to eat. Discard deeply dented cans. A deep dent is one that you can lay your finger into. Deep dents often have sharp points. A sharp dent on either the top or side seam can damage the seam and allow bacteria to enter the can. Discard any can with a deep dent on any seam.

So if you inspected the cans and found them ok, I would recommend you

- Store them at room temperature, not in the fridge, and
- Use them in the near future, not keep them for months or years.

Apart from that, I would probably check the inside of the can when open them, in case the inner lining was damaged and especially acidic foods (think canned tomatoes) caused oxidation or corrosion. I would probably discard them, not because of food safety issues, but because it may cause an unpleasant taste.

For cans with significant damage, the rules for opened cans apply: [Don’t store the food in open cans](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30498/is-it-ok-to-store-open-cans-in-the-fridge?rq=1), but empty the content in suitable containers and refrigerate.

——-

Edit, as I had a dented can at hand:

Under normal circumstances, I would probably have left this can at the store. But thanks to the recent wave of panic buying, a family member decided a dented can was better than none.

You can see that the edge of the dent doesn’t affect the seams, so no problem with leakage, and no subsequent food safety issues:

[image: exterior]

Also, the inner lining is intact, so no risk of the acidic content (tomatoes, in this case) corroding the metal. No problem either:

[image: interior]

Still, this was the can I decided to pull first from the pantry, only a week or so after it was bought. I don’t know when the damage happened, though. If I had noticed anything beyond a shape change, I would have discarded the whole can and used another.

Comment: Base on the pics what do you think I should do.  I saw that quote already but I can stick  my figures in some of them.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nUpj.jpg

Comment: Personally, I would use them. Soon-ish, but not worry too much.

Comment: Like a few weeks but less than a month should be fine?

Comment: Thanks.  SEeing if other answers before accepting this is a solution.

Comment: And it depends on the content. A bit, at least. If you can fit the most dented ones into the next week’s menu, go for it. But that’s _my personal opinion_.

Comment: The USDA says "A deep dent is one that you can lay your finger into." Maybe I'm being stupid, but I don't get what this means. Here's what the dent looks like: https://ex.plicat.io/bpt/can.html. Does anyone happen to know if this is too deep?